# How did people's liking of ceremonies evolve?

Tags: evolution, human-evolution

Habitual group activities are prevalent across many animal species, particularly in mammals, especially in primates.

However, I do not see any evolutionary benefit of this. 'Ceremonies' take time, and in many cases seem to exert more energy than they reap. Note at this point I am not talking about hunting groups, but rather about group activities that serve a purely social purpose (mourning is a  good example of this and is present in [elephants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_cognition#Death_ritual), [chimpanzees](http://www.livescience.com/6335-chimps-understand-mourn-death-research-suggests.html), [bonobos](http://www.earthisland.org/journal/index.php/elist/eListRead/chimps_and_bonobos_prove_that_moral_behavior_is_a_product_of_evolution/), and probably more). This costs significant amounts of resources, time, and energy which apparently could be better spent hunting, foraging, traveling, mating, or grazing.

I'm interested in finding a timeline, and explanation, of why and how this phenomenon of higher social rituals (perhaps using mourning as an example) evolved throughout the mammalian kingdom.

A cursory google revealed nothing about how this 'liking' of interaction evolved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an anthropological question.

Comment: We'll need an accurate definition of rituals in order to answer this question. For the moment it is too broad. Do you restrict rituals to social traditions? Do you include personal habits and obsessive behaviour in rituals? You posted several links (without much explanation), you should probably report what you read so far, that would help.

Comment: Questions about the evolution of human behaviour are on-topic to my opinion.

Comment: @AliceD The question is about evolution, and as far as I know, evolution falls firmly within the realm of biology. Perhaps it would be better on a anthropology Stack Exchange, but one does not exist.

Comment: @Remi.b Okay, I re-wrote the question. Do you have any ideas to further improve it?

Comment: Thank you the question is much improved this way, I retracted my close vote. Note however, that the question is not so much about evolutionary genetics but fall within the field of "evolution of traditions/culture", or more broadly speaking "evolution of memes" also called "[memetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memetics)", which is a field that has been created by biologists but in its current state is in between biology, sociology and philosophy. I think the question is on-topic but will appreciate to see what the others say. Might be a bit broad also...we'll see.

Comment: the question in it's present form does not have a biological perspective, the user thinks it is, but it's really more of a question of how did our cultures take the shape that they have today. What you can ask is why is our behaviour different from that of other animals, and how has it come to be so...

Comment: @KoustavPal What do you mean it doesn't have a biological perspective? Is there not some evolutionary advantage to ceremonies? Is that not biological?

Comment: no the evolution of ceremonies themselves have no biology, but neural development does, I'm not making myself clear. Ceremonies are our inventions, for instance mammalian males are generally polygamous, traditionally that has been so, in came the church and instituted monogamy, then in 19th century a few mistresses on the side were fine, and in the 20th century feminism started to pick up the pace and again we reverted to monogamy. So where is the evolutionary part of ceremonies. I will also point this out, the basal character of humans have not changed.

Comment: you would still prefer to sleep inside a closed space facing the point of entrance, why do you think that is?

Comment: @KoustavPal This is very far away from any biology particularly if you start talking about specific rituals from your own culture. For example, weddings in western culture have changed dramatically over the last century as media & adverts changed the concepts of a wedding. These are not biological evolutionary timescales.

Bird models are often used to study social dynamics, and primate studies often turn up habitual social group activities. Starting there might narrow down your question. Elephants have been observed mourning their dead too.

Comment: @KoustavPal I'm not asking how ceremonies evolved, as like you said, that would be cultural. I'm asking how the *liking* of ceremonies in general evolved. Given that this liking has existed for a very long time and is observed in other species, this seems genetic and biological.

Comment: @GoodGravy You might want to see the response I gave to KoustavPal.

Comment: Now I understand. You frame the question with in a very cultural-centric way. I'll try and suggest an edit.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k I have made some major edits to the question so feel free to roll back, but I think the question is back on topic. It still remains vague. If you can better define a "ceremony" or restrict it to mourning, then it will probably be specific enough to re-open.

Comment: @GoodGravy You made a good edit. I'm not sure how to make it less vague without taking away from the meaning of the question. I could try to narrow the question down to a specific ceremony, for example burials, but this would only give an answer to one small part of the question. I'll do this if you do not have any better ideas, though.

Comment: @GoodGravy Okay, I asked a new, more specific, [question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/37023/how-did-the-tendency-to-perform-death-rituals-evolve).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps customs (and culture as a whole) arises to some extent as a result of relationships between individuals of the same species. For example, I think a good example of a custom is how elephants bury their dead. This does not benefit the surviving elephants in any noticeable way, and is a "waste" of energy and time. If customs do arise because of a group dynamic, then there is clear evidence supporting that social behavior in higher organisms (chimpanzees, dolphins, etc.) does increase fitness.

However, this speculation is based upon the idea that customs are a natural result of social interaction. As to why these customs arise, perhaps it is because it enforces the group dynamic over the participating individuals.

Comment: I don't think elephants bury their dead, it's just that they appear to hesitate to move on from a dead elephant. Happy to be proven wrong!

Comment: ["...They then began to throw leaves and dirt over the body and broke off tree branches to cover her."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_cognition#Death_ritual) I stand corrected!