# How did the tendency to perform death rituals evolve?

Tags: evolution, ethology, death

Both [elephants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_cognition#Death_ritual) and humans perform rituals when deaths occur.

However, I do not see any evolutionary benefit of this. The rituals take time, which apparently could be better spent hunting, foraging, traveling, mating, or grazing.

I am interested to know if these behaviours have any significance and whether they confer any kind of survival advantage.

A cursory google revealed nothing about this.

Comment: Good read: http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20120919-respect-the-dead

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more the realm of anthropology. No, there is no Anthropology.SE and yes there is "evolution" in the question, but those two statements are not a reason to believe that all anthropologists are hiding at Biology.SE and that every question about evolution is on-topic here.

Comment: @AliceD It's not just about anthropology, because elephants have death rituals as well. Would it be best if I only ask how elephant death rituals originated?

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k I would suggest that you modify your question such that it is about animal behaviour. Please try adding details and if possible some more examples/references to support the point.

Comment: @WYSIWYG In what way is it not about animal behavior? The question is about death rituals, which is an animal behavior. Also, what point are you talking about? I am not trying to make a point in the question; I'm just asking a question.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k I meant that you add more emphasis on the animal behaviour part and defocus from the human aspect so that it is not interpreted as a question about anthropology. Gosh! I am trying to help you here; this question can be edited a little bit so that it can be on-topic. Why are you getting defensive?

Comment: @WYSIWYG My apologies; I did not intend to come across as defensive. I was just trying to better understand what was wrong with the question so I could improve it. What exactly made me seem like I was being defensive. Anyways, do you think asking only about elephant death rituals would be a good idea?

Comment: This question is not different enough from the [original question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36918/how-did-peoples-liking-of-ceremonies-evolve). If anything the original question is more on topic because it builds a strong case of showing that habitual social ceremony exists without anthropomorphism, whereas in this question it appears that you're trying to ask why it would benefit elephants to have human-like death rituals.